# Jquery access functions from an $.each loop

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes and want to do something with all the names of the checkboxes. But I can't seem to access the HTML objects:

```
$('.update').click(function(){
                $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i,elem){
                    console.log(elem);
                    elem.hide();
                });
            });
```

This produces TypeError: elem.hide is not a function

But the console.log(elem) shows: `<input type="checkbox" name="TV">`

How can I access each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the DOM node directly by using `elem`. You need to pass it to `$()` to get a jQuery object with access to `.hide()` and other jQuery methods:

```js
$('.update').click(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

elem is DOM element, not jquery type. You can use `$(elem).hide()` instead