# Jquery - append to all elements where id starts with using each

Tags: jquery

I want to use each fn to append elements to all divs where id starts with post. How to do it right?

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export const fn = (): void => {
  const $posts = $('[id^="post_id_"]')
  if ($posts.length === 0) return

  $posts.append('<h1>123</h1>') //works

  $posts.each((idx, el) => {
    // here i need to do some staff

    this.append('<h1>321</h1>') // jQuery.Deferred exception: this.append is not a function TypeError
    el.append('<h1>321</h1>') // append as string - not html
  })
}
```

Comment: [Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733627/jquery-access-functions-from-an-each-loop), but not quite (despite the title)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409039/jquery-each-this) one maybe?

Comment: @Andreas wrapping this not working too...

Comment: @RTW I also missed that you're using an arrow function which "messes" with `this` in the callback of `.each()`

Comment: @Andreas - I updated the accepted answer to your dupetarget so it covered using `this` or the second argument to the `each` callback. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `each` callback, `this` will be the same as it is outside the `each` callback because you're using an arror function, and `el` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. If you want to use jQuery methods on the element, use `$()` on it:

```
$(el).append('<h1>321</h1>');
```

Comment: Then i get: jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

https://i.imgur.com/dZhltHl.png

Comment: @RTW - Missed that you were using an arrow function; fixed it.

Comment: Omg, i forgot about arrow functions and this too, thanks!

Comment: @RTW - My pleasure! Happy coding!